# Inheritance and special types in Database design

Tags: database, inheritance, database-design

So I'm currently building an application that manages items which are closely related - sort of like an inventory for a store, e.g. hammer, nails, saw, etc. I have a table named lets say, items, that store the general info of each instance. There are other objects which share the same basic data (price, title, description, etc), but have extra features and information (suppose I also wanna sell lawn mowers, which'll have specifics like manufacturer, warranty, etc).

Is there a way to "inherit", so to speak, from another table or be a special instance of that type of entity? How should I tackle the design? Best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also consider an ORM like Hibernate which can handle this for you easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're building a relational database, you should have an `Item` table; "sub-classes" of items would have their own table, with their primary key also a foreign key to `Item`, thus creating 1:(0/1) relationships:

```
Item
----
ItemId (PK)
Price
Title


LawnMower
---------
ItemId (PK, FK to Item)
Manufacturer
Warranty

etc.
```

Comment: Ouh, so when I retrieve an item, i can simply pull info with same ItemID? even specifics?

Comment: Yep, you could do a join to pull in the specifics.

Comment: If I wanted to list all available items, I'd have to do an outter join right? Since attributes wont match on both sides?

Comment: If you wanted to join with all subclass tables to retrieve all details, yes you'd need to do outer joins. If you just wanted to pull, say, all lawn mowers, then you could use inner join to filter out items that weren't lawn mowers.